# Unit Testing in XCode

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode

I am trying to test some model classes that I've written with SenTest in XCode.  I have dragged the model header and implementation files into the `Compile Sources` group within my `LogicTests` target, and my tests pass.  The problem though is that I'm getting a ton of compiler warnings about no rule to process file such as:

```
warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/Speaker.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture i386
```

If I delete the header and implementation files from the `Compile Sources` group, then the tests don't pass.

What do I have configured wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

you do not need to include the headers in the "Compile Sources"

if you view the target membership in xcode, you will see that the header files are necessary, and should not be included

Comment: I removed all headers from both test and normal targets but I still get 7 of these warnings...